# What is a phrase/idiom that means "it's not easy being the leader" or "governing isn't easy"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms

I think there is some idiom for this like "It ain't easy being king" or "it's not easy running the world". Can't remember. Thanks.

Comment: There's always "Nobody knew health care could be so complicated."

Comment: Relevant: You campaign in poetry. You govern in prose. (Mario Cuomo)

Comment: @HotLicks I'm actually going to use that! "As draconian as the board may seem, the residents hardly make governing easy. In the words of one famous leader--nobody knew it could be so complicated."

Answer (score 4):

"It ain't easy being king" is one that I've heard used. Presumably it's a reworking of "Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown." from Shakespeare's *Henry the Fourth, Part 2 Act 3, scene 1, 26–31*

> Canst thou, O partial sleep, give thy repose
>   To the wet sea-boy in an hour so rude,
>   And in the calmest and most stillest night,
>   With all appliances and means to boot,
>   Deny it to a king? Then happy low, lie down!
>   Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown.

The phrase has also been altered to "Heavy is the head that wears the crown".

Comment: Of course, ["It's not easy being green"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpiIWMWWVco) is the more familiar phrase.